# How to find the last day of a Quarter, Half Year and Year of current Financial Year in DB2?

Tags: sql, date, db2

I would like to get the last day of a Quarter, Half Year and Year of current Financial Year in DB2. Our Financial year starts from 1st of April and ends on 31st of March. So, if the today's date is 02-Oct-2016, the Quarter end date will be 31-Dec-2016, Half Year date will be 31-Mar-2017 and Year end date will be 31-Mar-2017. Similarily, if the input date is 07-May-2016, then the the Quarter end date will be 30-Jun-2016, Half Year date will be 30-Sep-2016 and Year end date will be 31-Mar-2017.

I am able to get the last date of a month using the last_day function in DB2, but I am unable to do the same for getting the other 3 dates. I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Create a FiscalDates DB2 table and load it with the dates you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the number of the month within a quarter (i.e. 1/2/3) and then add 2 months for the 1st month of a quarter and 1 month for the 2nd quarter (`MOD(2-(MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1),3)` = 0/1/2). Now your month is always 3/6/9/12 and you can apply `last_day`.

I don't have a DB2 system to test it, but the syntax seems to be like this:

```
LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE + (MOD(2-(CURRENT_DATE-1),3) MONTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do some really flexible stuff with dates, but there's nothing specific in DB2 (that I know of) to be able to find dates for relevant financial quarters, so a little bit of case statements around the current month will probably be needed.

```
SELECT MONTH(CURRENT DATE), -- returns 10

       CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS, --return first day of current month

       CASE WHEN 
               MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3) = 0
               THEN 3
          ELSE MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3)
       END, --months into the quarter, so 1 for first month, 2 for second month, 3 for last month


       CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS +
       (4 - CASE WHEN 
                  MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3) = 0
                   THEN 3
                 ELSE MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3)
       END) MONTHS, --returns first day of next quarter


       CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS +
                      (4 - CASE WHEN 
                                    MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3) = 0
                                      THEN 3
                                ELSE MOD(MONTH(CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE) - 1) DAYS), 3)
                       END) MONTHS
       - 1 DAY -- returns last day of current quarter
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

You could then use some case statements around the current month to find similar info for the half year and next year.

I know this looks a little messy, but it'll do the job. I would suggest using this code to create a scalar function that you can easily reuse to find the quarter, and have something similar for half year and full year.

Sources: Work as a Business Intelligence Analyst with DB2 every day

Answer (score 0):

Validation of the queries and routines given here, was done on the DB2 for IBM i 7.3 [aka v7r3]

No indication of how the data would be used [so as to know in what form the data is needed or could be provided], but the following User Defined Table Function (UDTF) defines some constants that represent a mapping/correlation from the incoming MONTH [of the optional DATE as input; defaulting to CURRENT DATE if no argument is supplied], to the months of both the End-Of-Quarter and the End-Of-Half, and to the Quarter; that mapping allows for some fairly simple date arithmetic to give the desired values, without creating an actual [persistent] calendar-table:

```
create function OUR_FINANCIAL_YEAR_DATES                       
( input_date date default current date )                       
returns table                                                  
( "Last_Day_Of_Quarter"   /* for LD_QTR  */ date               
, "Last_Day_Of_Half_Year" /* for LD_HALF */ date               
, "Last_Day_Of_Year"      /* for LD_YEAR */ date               
) language sql                                                 
return                                                         
 with                                                          
   moMap ( mo, hAddMo, qAddMo, q ) as ( values                 
      ( 12, 3 , 0 , 3 ), ( 11, 4 , 1 , 3 ), ( 10, 5 , 2 , 3 )  
    , (  9, 0 , 0 , 2 ), (  8, 1 , 1 , 2 ), (  7, 2 , 2 , 2 )  
    , (  6, 3 , 0 , 1 ), (  5, 4 , 1 , 1 ), (  4, 5 , 2 , 1 )  
    , (  3, 0 , 0 , 4 ), (  2, 1 , 1 , 4 ), (  1, 2 , 2 , 4 ) )
 , endFYdates ( end_Qtr, end_Hyr, end_Fyr ) as                 
   ( select                                                    
       last_day( input_date   +  qAddMo MONTHS )     as Qtr_end
     , last_day( input_date   +  hAddMo MONTHS )     as Hyr_end
     , last_day( input_date   + (qAddMo + ( 3 * ( 4 - q ) )    
                                )       MONTHS )     as Fyr_end
     from moMap as M                                           
     where mo = month( input_date   )                          
   )                                                           
 select end_Qtr, end_Hyr, end_Fyr                              
 from endFYdates
```

Of course a scalar User Defined Function (UDF) could easily enough use the above UDTF to implement getting any one of those values; perhaps with a second argument identifying which of those DATE values to return.

```
with                                                                
  variousDates ( dv ) as ( values                                   
  ( date'2016-05-01' ), ( date'2016-05-02' ), ( date'2016-06-30' )  
, ( date'2016-07-02' ), ( date'2016-08-02' ), ( date'2016-09-30' )  
, ( date'2016-10-01' ), ( date'2016-11-02' ), ( date'2016-12-30' )  
, ( date'2017-01-02' ), ( date'2017-03-02' ), ( date'2017-03-30' ) )
select vdv.*, fyv.*                                                 
     , dec( quarter( vdv.dv - 3 months ) , 1 ) as qtr               
from variousDates as vdv                                            
, lateral                                                           
  ( select s.* from table(OUR_FINANCIAL_YEAR_DATES(vdv.dv)) as s    
  ) as fyv                                                          
order by 1                                                          
; -- a likeness of a report from the above query:
DV          LAST_00001  LAST_00002  LAST_00003  QTR
2016-05-01  2016-06-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   1 
2016-05-02  2016-06-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   1 
2016-06-30  2016-06-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   1 
2016-07-02  2016-09-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   2 
2016-08-02  2016-09-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   2 
2016-09-30  2016-09-30  2016-09-30  2017-03-31   2 
2016-10-01  2016-12-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   3 
2016-11-02  2016-12-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   3 
2016-12-30  2016-12-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   3 
2017-01-02  2017-03-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   4 
2017-03-02  2017-03-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   4 
2017-03-30  2017-03-31  2017-03-31  2017-03-31   4 
********  End of data  ********
```

The following UDTF *calculates* the End-Of-Quarter for a given DATE value as input [for the CURRENT_DATE, if there is no argument passed], but additionally calculates and provides the Start-Of-Quarter and End-Of_Quarter values for each quarter from that calculated date, plus provides the calculated result for the End-Of-Half, End-Of-Year, and Quarter of the given DATE value:

```
create function THE_FINANCIAL_YEAR_DATES          
( input_date date default current date )          
returns table                                     
( LastOfQtr               /* for LD_QTR  */ date  
, LastOfHalf              /* for LD_HALF */ date  
, LastOfYear              /* for LD_YEAR */ date  
, NumberQtr               /* for NO_QTR  */ dec(1)
, FirstOfQ1               /* for FD_Q1   */ date  
, Last_OfQ1               /* for LD_Q1   */ date  
, FirstOfQ2               /* for FD_Q2   */ date  
, Last_OfQ2               /* for LD_Q2   */ date  
, FirstOfQ3               /* for FD_Q3   */ date  
, Last_OfQ3               /* for LD_Q3   */ date  
, FirstOfQ4               /* for FD_Q4   */ date  
, Last_OfQ4               /* for LD_Q4   */ date  
) language sql                                    
return                                                              
 with                                                               
   endCurQtr  ( ecq , q ) as                                        
     ( values                                                       
        ( LAST_DAY(   input_date                                    
                    + ( MOD( 1 - MONTH( input_date )                
                           , 3 ) + 2                                
                      ) MONTHS                                      
                  )                                                 
        , DEC( QUARTER( input_date - 3 MONTHS ), 1 )                
        )                                                           
     )                                                              
, curFYdates (q, ecq, sQ1, eQ1, sQ2, eQ2, sQ3, eQ3, sQ4, eQ4, eHY) as
  ( select q, ecq,                                                  
      ( ecq + 1 day )   - (   3 * ( q     )  ) months               
    , last_day( ( ecq ) - (   3 * ( q - 1 )  ) months )             
    , ( ecq + 1 day )   - (   3 * ( q - 1 )  ) months               
    , last_day( ( ecq ) - (   3 * ( q - 2 )  ) months )        
    , ( ecq + 1 day )   - (   3 * ( q - 2 )  ) months          
    , last_day( ( ecq ) - (   3 * ( q - 3 )  ) months )        
    , ( ecq + 1 day )   - (   3 * ( q - 3 )  ) months          
    , last_day( ( ecq ) - (   3 * ( q - 4 )  ) months )        
    , last_day( ( ecq ) - (   3 * ( q -                        
           case when q>2 then 4 else 2 end)  ) months )        
    from endCurQtr                                             
  )                                                            
select ecq, eHY, eQ4, q, sQ1, eQ1, sQ2, eQ2, sQ3, eQ3, sQ4, eQ4
from curFYdates
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using to calculate the last day of the previous quarter:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT DATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 3 
THEN DATE(YEAR(CURRENT DATE) -1 || '-12-31')  
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT DATE) BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
THEN DATE(YEAR(CURRENT DATE) || '-03-31') 
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT DATE) BETWEEN 7 AND 9 
THEN DATE(YEAR(CURRENT DATE) || '-06-30') 
WHEN MONTH(CURRENT DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 12 
THEN DATE(YEAR(CURRENT DATE) || '-09-30')END AS QTR_END 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```